# Mocha checking for global variable leaks outside of the main directory - it is checking node modules

Tags: memory-leaks, gruntjs, mocha.js

Mocha is detecting for global variable leaks in node_modules. 
I see this
`global leak detected: Promise Error: global leak detected: Promise`
I fixed this error by adding it in the globals list
`globals: ['moment' , 'Promise']`

But I do not understand why this is happening? Am I missing something here?

I understand that this come from the node_modules. Because if I remove one of the modules(the one which has `Promise` as a global variable) then all the tests passes.

Thanks!